# Send encrypted data through socket fail

Tags: c, sockets, encryption, openssl, rsa

I am trying to first encrypt one file and send it to server, both client and server are all written in C openssl. I try to encrypt one file and decrypt it in server, but when decrypting I got an error:

```
error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02
```

I checked this error for a long time and fail to modify it.

Here is part of my code:

RSA:I think this part is fine, becaue in the client I decrypt it immediately after encryption, and it success.

int padding = RSA_PKCS1_PADDING;

```
RSA * createRSA(unsigned char * key,int public)
{
    RSA *rsa= NULL;
    BIO *keybio ;
    keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, -1);
    if (keybio==NULL)
    {
        printf( "Failed to create key BIO");
        return 0;
    }
    if(public)
    {
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    }
    if(rsa == NULL)
    {
        printf( "Failed to create RSA");
    }

    return rsa;
}

 char publicKey[]="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"\
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAy8Dbv8prpJ/0kKhlGeJY\n"\
"ozo2t60EG8L0561g13R29LvMR5hyvGZlGJpmn65+A4xHXInJYiPuKzrKUnApeLZ+\n"\
"vw1HocOAZtWK0z3r26uA8kQYOKX9Qt/DbCdvsF9wF8gRK0ptx9M6R13NvBxvVQAp\n"\
"fc9jB9nTzphOgM4JiEYvlV8FLhg9yZovMYd6Wwf3aoXK891VQxTr/kQYoq1Yp+68\n"\
"i6T4nNq7NWC+UNVjQHxNQMQMzU6lWCX8zyg3yH88OAQkUXIXKfQ+NkvYQ1cxaMoV\n"\
"PpY72+eVthKzpMeyHkBn7ciumk5qgLTEJAfWZpe4f4eFZj/Rc8Y8Jj2IS5kVPjUy\n"\
"wQIDAQAB\n"\
"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

 char privateKey[]="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
/* ----8<---------------------*/
"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

int public_encrypt(unsigned char * data,int data_len,unsigned char * key, unsigned char *encrypted)
{
    RSA * rsa = createRSA(key,1);
    int result = RSA_public_encrypt(data_len,data,encrypted,rsa,padding);
    return result;
}
int private_decrypt(unsigned char * enc_data,int data_len,unsigned char * key, unsigned char *decrypted)
{
    RSA * rsa = createRSA(key,0);
    int  result = RSA_private_decrypt(data_len,enc_data,decrypted,rsa,padding);
    if(result==-1){
    printf("in\n");
    unsigned int errCode = ERR_get_error();

    printf("\nError: %s\n", ERR_error_string(errCode, NULL));

    }
    return result;
}
```

Socket:

```
int readData(int s, void *buf, int buflen)
{
    int total = 0;
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    while (buflen > 0) {
        int numread = recv(s, pbuf, buflen, 0);
        if (numread <= 0) return numread;
        pbuf += numread;
        buflen -= numread;
        total += numread;
    }
    return total;
}

int sendData(int s, void *buf, int buflen)
{
    int total = 0;
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    while (buflen > 0) {
        int numsent = send(s, pbuf, buflen, 0);
        if (numsent <= 0) return numsent;
        pbuf += numsent;
        buflen -= numsent;
        total += numsent;
    }
    return total;
}
```

client:(this is not the whole code I just pick some important code, the decrypt here just to test, and it success to decrypt)

```
unsigned char  encrypted[8192]={};
unsigned char decrypted[8192]={};
char buffer[8192];
bzero(buffer,8192);
stream = fopen(save_name,"w+t");
struct stat st ;
stat( put_name, &st );
fread(buffer,1,st.st_size,stream))
int encrypted_length=public_encrypt(buffer,st.st_size,publicKey,encrypted);
printf("after encrypted%s\n", encrypted);
int decrypted_length= private_decrypt(encrypted,256,privateKey,decrypted);
printf("afterdecrypted: %s\n",decrypted);
sendData(fd,encrypted,strlen(encrypted))
```

server:

```
readData(connfd,buf,intsize);
("recieve data buf:%s\n", buf);
unsigned char  decrypted[8192]={};
bzero(decrypted,8192);
int decrypted_length = private_decrypt(buf,256,privateKey,decrypted);
```

I used md5 to check the sent and received data, they are the same. Could you find the reason?

Here is another question, with same error, but I can't get any idea from here.
[Encryption and decryption error 0x0407106B using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275592/encryption-and-decryption-error-0x0407106b-using-openssl)

I use

```
printf("in server: \ndata:%s\nlength:%d\nkeylen:%d\n",buf,strlen(buf),strlen(privateKey) );
```

to print all perimeters and they are same.

```
in server: 
data:k???
U??uE????^??%?^{?N?-?pg???5?|??
???$???ěQ????zܯ?(T?n>f&??J?C??x?
D
length:82
keylen:1675

in client: 
data:k???
U??uE????^??%?^{?N?-?pg???5?|??
???$???ěQ????zܯ?(T?n>f&??J?C??x?
D
length:82
keylen:1675
```

When I use the valgrind, it shows a lot of problem, the first is:

```
==21631== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 35
==21631==    at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==21631==    by 0x31CF06AC2D: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==21631==    by 0x31CF0A72C1: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==21631==    by 0x31CF0A742C: bn_expand2 (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==21631==    by 0x31CF0A7674: BN_copy (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==21631==    by 0x31CF0A7899: BN_dup (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==21631==    by 0x31CF0ABE2C: BN_BLINDING_create_param (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==21631==    by 0x31CF0CC500: RSA_setup_blinding (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==21631==    by 0x31CF0C4483: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==21631==    by 0x31CF0C49C7: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==21631==    by 0x402263: put_file (client.c:442)
==21631==    by 0x402675: main (client.c:628)
```

the line 442 is my decrypt function. So, any problem with my decryption function.

Comment: Is the `private_decrypt` on the server the same as on the client? What about the `padding` global? Is it the same?

Comment: yes,same, I copy it

Comment: Well if the data is the same (are you sure? maybe you are hashing just a partial data?) and the code is the same, there is really no reason for them to behave differently on the client and the server. Unless you have different openssl versions on the two...

Comment: You have just fatally compromised your private key. This is a **MAJOR** security breach. You must now throw it away, generate a new keypair, and avoid posting it on the Internet completely.

Comment: the key is copied from internet

Comment: Irrelevant. If you're using it as your private key it has to be private. Otherwise the entire exercise is just a complete waste of time.